# using DataStax graphdb, How to create vertexIndex using multiple columns with materialized view method

Tags: graph-databases, datastax-enterprise

I am using gremlin data loader to load the csv file to vertex and edges. Tte problem I have is that I have a vertex with multiple (more than 3) keys as PK of the vertex. When loading the file, it is giving an error, that it can not create an index on more than one column, and when I create an index, it is giving an error on two keys.

It can create search type index on multiple keys. But search isn't enabled at the moment. I am looking for a syntax to create materilized view on multiple columns.

e.g.

```
schema.vertexLabel('recipe').index('search').search().by('instructions').asText().by('category').asString().add()   -- this should work..  but I want
schema.vertexLabel('recipe').index('search').materialized().by('instructions').asText().by('category').asString().add() -- does not work..
```

Answer (score 0):

DSE Graph leverages Apache Cassandra's MV functionality for the MV indexes.  At the current time, Cassandra does not support multiple col indexes with MVs.  You can see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9928 for more information.  Right now DSE Search integration is required if you would like to index multiple properties.